# WPF RadioButton - Override state change

Tags: .net, wpf, radio-button

In .NET Framework v4.0, is it possible to override the state change of a WPF `RadioButton`?

In the XAML below, I'm using a Listbox to display a dynamic number of Items, of which a single item is deemed the "Selected Item".

```
<ListBox Height="Auto"
         Name="listBoxItems"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Items}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=UserSelectedItem}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton GroupName="SameGroup" Checked="OnItemSelected" IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource itemDescriptionConverter}}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When clicking a RadioButton, the OnItemSelected method will do some validation, and then provide a Dialog box informing the User that the new "Selected Item" will be saved.

In the event of an Error condition, or the User cancelling the Save, I was wanting the RadioButton state change to be reset / overridden. ie I manually change the value of the IsSelected property.

Debugging this through I see the following sequence of Events.

1. Radio button is checked causing `IsSelected` property change value, and a `NotifyPropertyEvent` to be fired
2. The new value of the `IsSelected` property is read.
3. The `OnSelected` method is called, resulting in a Dialog box.
4. The user cancels the action, and I manually call `IsSelected` on each bound object, resetting values back. This fires off multiple `NotifyPropertyEvents`.
5. The reset values are NEVER re-read.

Comment: If it is a Radio button then only one can be selected so why multiple resets?  Try no Event and call the Dialog box in the Set.  If they cancel then simply don't set value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some code where I clear any RadioButtons and it is working for me.  Review your code.  The event is NotifyPropertyChanged not NotifyProperty.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cbs}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton GroupName="UserType" Content="{Binding Path=name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=chcked, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>


    public class cb: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        private bool c = false;
        public bool chcked 
        {
            get { return c; }
            set 
            {
                if (c == value) return;
                c = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("chcked");
            } 
        }
        public string name { get; private set; }
        public cb(string _name) { name = _name; }
    }

    private void btnClickClearAll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (cb c in cbs.Where(x => x.chcked))
        {
            c.chcked = false;
        }
    }

    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbs[0].chcked) cbs[0].chcked = false;   
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code sample. Yes Im raising NotifyPropertyChanged events. Interestingly, Ive just implemented a Button than when clicked resets the state of the RadioButton, like your example above!! So the Bindings are working, but not when its set through the Checked event of the RadioButton?!?

Comment: Then as I suggested in my comment don't mix binding with event.  Do it all in the set.

Comment: I mixed in an event with binding and it worked.  The dialog may be the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will remove the dialog and see if it makes a difference